# SQL Query for count by month over multiple years

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been using the query below to get me a count of records by month. Works good for a specific year.

However, its a bit of a pain if I want to compare a count from Jan 2018 to Jan 2019. Especially if I want to graph it.

How might I adjust this so that I could get a Jan 18, Feb 18,....Jan 19 type of result by giving a span of years.

This is Postgres 9.6

Thanks!

```
SELECT
  count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '01' then 1 END) as Jan,
  count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '02' then 1 END) as Feb,
  count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '03' then 1 END) as Mar,
  count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '04' then 1 END) as Apr,
  count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '05' then 1 END) as May,
  count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '06' then 1 END) as June,
  count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '07' then 1 END) as Jul,
  count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '08' then 1 END) as Aug,
  count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '09' then 1 END) as Sep,
  count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '10' then 1 END) as Oct,
  count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '11' then 1 END) as Nov,
  count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '12' then 1 END) as Dec
FROM transactions as t
WHERE to_char(t.order_date, 'YYYY') = '2019'
```

Comment: How about just: `count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM-YY') = '01-18' then 1 END) as Jan18` ?

Comment: But then I'd have to have an entry for every month of every year I want to show. I'd rather I just supply a year range, or list of years and have it run.

Comment: No. A sql query neeeds to return a *fixed* set of columns. If you want a separate column in the results for each year/month, this means a dynamic number of columns (depending on the year range)...

Comment: Why not do `WHERE to_char(t.order_date, 'YYYY') BETWEEN '2017'
AND '2019'`?

Answer (score 1):

You can make “buckets” of your data by timestamp, by combining:

- [Truncate a timestamp value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) to a specified precision, flattening those values to a single value.
- [Group by](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY) the resulting lower-precision values.

```sql
SELECT
    date_trunc('month', t.order_date) AS order_month,
    count(t.order_id) AS count
FROM transaction AS t
GROUP BY order_month
ORDER BY order_month
```

Then it's up to you what years to limit the result to:

```sql
SELECT
    date_trunc('month', t.order_date) AS order_month,
    count(t.order_id) AS count
FROM transaction AS t
WHERE
    date_part('year', t.order_date) = 2019
GROUP BY order_month
ORDER BY order_month
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Please check below query, is this relevant?
```

> Blockquote

SELECT 
      to_char(order_date, 'YYYY'),
      count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '01' then 1 END) as Jan,
      count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '02' then 1 END) as Feb,
      count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '03' then 1 END) as Mar,
      count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '04' then 1 END) as Apr,
      count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '05' then 1 END) as May,
      count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '06' then 1 END) as June,
      count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '07' then 1 END) as Jul,
      count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '08' then 1 END) as Aug,
      count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '09' then 1 END) as Sep,
      count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '10' then 1 END) as Oct,
      count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '11' then 1 END) as Nov,
      count(case when to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '12' then 1 END) as Dec
      FROM transactions as t where to_char(order_date, 'YYYY') in ('2018','2019')
      group by to_char(order_date, 'YYYY');

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the results on different rows?

```
SELECT to_char(t.order_date, 'YYYY') = '2019',
       count(*) filter (to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '01') as Jan,
       count(*) filter (to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '02') as Feb,
       . . .
       count(*) filter (to_char(t.order_date, 'MM') = '12') as Dec
FROM transactions as t
GROUP BY to_char(t.order_date, 'YYYY') = '2019'
```